# git: how to interactive rebase commits found in remote branch B on top of local branch A?

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-rebase

I am basically wanting to interactively rebase 2 changes (shas 1a28dba and be7c442) found in remote-branch-b, on top of local-branch-a so I can push them to remote-branch-a.

I tried this (along with a few other variations); however, **the changes I were looking for weren't applied after the rebas**e; I believe I had local-branch-**b** checked out when I executed this:

```
git rebase -i --onto local-branch-a remote-branch-b
```

The results in the interactive session are weird; not sure what the **noop** is; however, the shas are correct (i.e. *Rebase 10b67a636..10b67a636 onto 8d00e80c2 (1 command)*):

```
noop
# Rebase 10b67a636..10b67a636 onto 8d00e80c2 (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified); use -c <commit> to reword the commit message
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what it looks like over here? `git log --oneline --graph remote-branch-a remote-branch-b local-branch-a` and pinpoint what revisions you would like to rebase (first revision to be rebased, last one and such).

Comment: @eftshift0  1a28dba and  be7c442

Comment: Well, I provided the recipe in the answer (I just undeleted it) so that it rebases the last two revisions of `remote-branch-b` on top of `remote-branch-a`.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it like this:

```
git rebase --onto remote-branch-a remote-branch-b~2 remote-branch-b
```

Use `-i` if you *really* need to do something interactive with it.

update: Maybe what you meant to run was:

```
git rebase --onto remote-branch-a local-branch-a remote-branch-b
```

That should work if local-branch-a is 2 revisions behind remote-branch-b

Comment: it was actually revisions 3 and 4, how would I indicate that?

Comment: It's actually about counting back from the tip of the branch... so if it's the _last_ two revisions of the branch, the **first** command I provided will still hold water.

Comment: if it's not the last 2 revisions but some other 2 revisions in the middle (but they are one after the other) then run this: `git rebase --onto remote-branch-a latter-revision~2 latter-revision` (`latter-revision` being the latest of the 2 revisions you want to rebase).